# App Hanging: "App hanging for at least 2000 ms" reported by Sentry

Tags: react-native, react-native-sentry

I've been encountering the "App hanging for at least 2000 ms" issue multiple times while using Sentry. The app seems to be experiencing significant delays, and I'm having trouble pinpointing the root cause of the problem.

**Environment:**

- @sentry/react-native: ^5.11.1
- React Native: 0.72.4
- Platform: iOS

**Additional Information**

I've checked the following without success:

> Reviewed the Sentry documentation for common causes of performance issues.
> Ensured that my dependencies are up to date.
> Checked network requests for potential bottlenecks.

Screenshots:
[image: Sentry screen]

Comment: Do you have animations in your app?

Comment: @M.N.
 Yes, there is little animation inside the navigation. The issue started showing four months ago, but now it's more frequent. I can't relate the reason
The app is 4 years old, and we are maintaining it.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue after upgrading to react native 0.72.5

Comment: @fancy-john still facing the same issue with no luck. Do you use RN SVG?

Comment: @MShokry yes I use react-native-svg. And I still didn't figure out where the problem is

Comment: We are seeing a similar issue and have found suggestions that the UIPasteboard permissions notification may be leading to Sentry reporting these "App Hanging" events. See https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/discussions/2715

Answer (score 1):

You need to Improve your application performance

**How?**

- Reduce App Size With Code Splitting and Lazy Loading
- Make Use of Uncontrolled Inputs
  Make Use of Memory Optimization
- Make Use of Hermes
- Enable the RAM Format
- Make Use of InteractionManager
- Avoid Anonymous Functions While Rendering
- Remove Console Statements
- Avoid the Use of ScrollView to Render Huge Lists
- Avoid Passing Inline Functions as Props
- Use Cache Images or local images must be webp type image
- Use nativeDriver With the Animated Library
- Avoid Arrow Functions
- Avoid Excessive Use of Higher-Order Components
- Use Style References Correctly

Or you can disable the warning if you want

The app hang detection integration has a default timeout of two (2) seconds and You can change the timeout by setting the appHangTimeoutInterval option:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react-native";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "DSN",
  appHangTimeoutInterval: 1,
});
```

Comment: @shivoham-0 I need to know the root cause of the issue itself. Any recommendations?

Comment: yes check this https://brainhub.eu/library/react-native-performance#:~:text=Memory%20leakage%2C%20a%20React%20Native,or%20VirtualList%2C%20instead%20of%20ListView.

Comment: Improve your application performance

Comment: check my answer  is edited

Comment: Appreciate your excellent response! We'll certainly follow your advice. The problem first appeared four months ago and has become more frequent since then. I'm having trouble pinpointing the cause. The app is four years old, and we've been maintaining it.

Comment: Oh, you need to update your project, because the new version in React Native is more performant than the old version

Comment: Just update your project after that your problem will be solved